# Resizing jpg's with javascript in Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jpeg, image-size

I'm using jquery and Raphael to create an interface with cards that can be moved around and have different images on them. I've created rect objects with the images as fills. Currently the images can only be the size of the original image but I want to resize them to make them twice as long (the original images are 40 pixels wide and high, but I want them to be 80). How can I do this without changing the original files?

Here's my code:

```
for(var i = 71; i > 0; i--){

    var card_name = orderRecord[i - 1];//orderRecord is a randomly ordered array of ints between 1 and 72

    //the images are titled 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', etc. 
    cards[card_name] = main_canvas.rect(10, 10, 80, 80).attr('fill','url(images/thumbnails/image' + card_name + '.jpg)');
}
```

Comment: can you pop it on a fiddle ?

Answer (score 3):

You could scale an element with Raphael's [Element.transform()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) method.

Double width:

```
cards[card_name].transform( [ '...s2,1' ] );
```

Double width and height:

```
cards[card_name].transform( [ '...s2,2' ] );
```